# Export Web Content structures and templates in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is it possible to export *only* Web Content structures and/or templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for the most part anyway.  If you go into the Control Panel then go into Web Content, you should notice a wrench icon for the portlet.  When you go into Export/Import, you can uncheck everything except for the `Structures, Templates, and Feeds` box.  I haven't checked to see if they fixed it yet, but I recall this did not work in 6.0 in the `Global` community.